# How can I transpose and add a new column with a value referred from one of the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading a csv file with the below dataframe:

```
0  Type     Jan-15 Feb-15 Mar-15 Apr-15 May-15 Jun-15
1  Staff       1       3     4       2     2      1
2  Business    2       1     2       3     2      2
3  Parking     1       4     3       3     1      1
```

My end goal is 1) to transpose the df and 2) to add a quarter column; something along this line

```
   Type     Staff Business Parking quarter
   Jan-15     1      2      1        q1
   Feb-15     3      1      4        q1
   Mar-15     4      2      3        q1
   Apr-15     2      3      3        q2
   May-15     2      2      1        q2
   Jun-15     1      2      1        q2
```

So far I transposed using this

```
dft = df.set_index('Type').transpose()
```

However I'm struggling with adding the quarter column and filling in the quarter. I've given this a try with no success

```
dft['quarter'] = dft['Type'].str.extract(r'(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun)').map({'Jan':'Q1', 'Feb':'Q1','Mar':'Q1','Apr':'Q2','May':'Q2','Jun':'Q2'})
```

Any help of what I've done wrong? Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: After transpose `Type` is the index of `dft` so you would need to use `dft.index` instead of `dft['Type']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `Type` is index not column name

```py
dft['quarter'] = dft.index.str.extract(r'(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun)')[0].map({'Jan':'Q1', 'Feb':'Q1','Mar':'Q1','Apr':'Q2','May':'Q2','Jun':'Q2'}).values
```

```
Type    Staff   Business    Parking quarter
Jan-15  1   2   1   Q1
Feb-15  3   1   4   Q1
Mar-15  4   2   3   Q1
Apr-15  2   3   3   Q2
May-15  2   2   1   Q2
Jun-15  1   2   1   Q2
```